# Postfix queue keeps growing

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, flush

im having some trouble with our mail server since yesterday.

First, the server was down for couple days, thanks to KVM, VMs were paused because storage was apparently full. So i managed to fix the issue. But since the mail server is back online, CPU usage was always at 100%, i checked logs, and there was "millions", of mails waiting in the postfix queue.

I tried to flush the queue, thanks to the PFDel script, it took some times, but all mails were gone, and we were finally able to receive new emails. I also forced a logrotate, because fail2ban was also using lots of CPU.

Unfortunately, after couple hours, postfix active queue is still growing, and i really dont understand why.

Another script i found is giving me that result right now:

Incoming: 1649
Active: 10760
Deferred: 0
Bounced: 2
Hold: 0
Corrupt: 0

is there a possibility to desactivate ""Undelivered Mail returned to Sender" ?

Any help would be very helpful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could firstly temporarily stop sending bounce mails completely or set more strict rules in order to analyze the reasons of the flood. See for example:
http://domainhostseotool.com/how-to-configure-postfix-to-stop-sending-undelivered-mail-returned-to-sender-emails-thoroughly.html

Sometimes the spammers find some weakness (or even vulnerability) in your configuration or in SMTP server and using that to send the spam (also if it could reach the addressee via bounce only). Mostly in this case, you will find your IP/domain in some common blacklist services (or it will be blacklisted by large mail providers very fast), so this will participate additionally to the flood (the bounces will be rejected by recipient server, what then let grow you queue still more).

So also check your IP/domain using https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx or similar service (sometimes they provide also the reason why it was blocked).

As for fail2ban, you can also analyze logs (find some pattern) to detect the evildoers (initial sender), and write custom RE for fail2ban to ban them for example after 10 attempts in 20 minutes (or add it to ignore list for bounce messages in postfix)... so you'd firstly send X bounces, but hereafter it'd ban the recidive IPs, what could also help to reduce the flood significantly.

An last but not least, check your config (follow best practices for it) and set up at least MX/SPF records, DKIM signing/verification and DMARC policies.